# Angular - Store login info for current user

Tags: angularjs

I am building an Angular application, and I have home page where the user will see, I want to display on the right side of the page a button saying: Login. If the user is not yet logged in, I want this exact button to have a list of "Account Settings" and "Logout" if the user is already logged in.

I am using routing in my app, so when the user lands on the home page, I don't load any controller (yet). I am loading controller based on the $state in the app configuration to load controller for each view.

Where do I store user's login state in order to change the buttons to say login or logout? Do I need to make a controller for the homepage? I am lost here and any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your going to use ng-show/ng-hide and ng-click. So your going to show the button if a user is not logged in.

this will look something like:

```
<button ng-hide="isLoggedIn()" ng-click"login()">Login</a></button>
<button ng-show="isLoggedIn()" ng-click"showSettings()">Account Settings</a></button>
<button ng-show="isLoggedIn()" ng-click"logout()">Logout</a></button>
```

the controller will look something like

```
$scope.isLoggedIn = Auth.isLoggedIn;    // code to check if user is logged in
```

When a user logs in, they will get a cookie stored.  So you want to figure out a way to check if the cookie is there.  The 'Auth' above is a factory that uses a function isLoggedIn to check if the user's cookie is present.

There are lots of examples online if you search for this.  I use Angular Full Stack (yeoman) for authorization but there are simpler ways that don't incorporate a backend.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. So each time the user refreshes the page I need to check if he's logged in?

Comment: The common use you have Navigation links - so if a user is not logged in there will be the login, home links.  Then once logged in you will see logout, profile, settings...  It happens almost instantaneous, because with SPAs all the JS code is downloaded once, when the app is initially loaded. Here is a repo - so you can see a production style use case of check out components/nav and the corresponding controllers  https://github.com/jakblak/MEAN-Projects/tree/master/AuthStarter